# Raphael - How to handle click on empty area?

Tags: raphael

I have some elements like circles & paths on my canvas that created with raphaeljs. i just want handle click when user click on empty area of canvas.

i try to set click event on canvas/svg elemnt in raphael but its fire every where and i just want fire when i clicked in empty area.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vpGyL/1389/

```
var r = Raphael('testGraph', 500, 500);
r.circle(200,200,100).attr({"fill":"#0F0"});
r.path("M100,100L200, 200").attr({
    stroke: "#F00",
    fill: "none",
    "stroke-width": 3
});
r.canvas.onclick = function(){alert("filled & empty area clicked togethere")};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution similar to Rodrigo's is just to check the event target, and check for its type, or id or whatever...

```
r.canvas.onclick = function( ev ){
   if( ev.target.localName == 'svg' ) {
        alert('svg');
   };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you implement a flag which is set `true` when an element was clicked. It could look like this:

```
var elementClickFunction = function() {elementClicked = true;};
circle.click(elementClickFunction);
```

In the canvas click function you check whether the `elementClicked` flag is true or false and reset it.

```
r.canvas.onclick = function(){
    if(elementClicked) {
        alert('element clicked!');
        elementClicked = false;
    }
    else {
        alert('whitespace clicked!');
    }
};
```

Here an example in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/vpGyL/1392/